# Tricky Contest Problem

Tags: contest-math, systems-of-equations

If $x, y$ and $z$ are real numbers with
\begin{align*}
x(x+y+z)&=2-yz\\
y(x+y+z)&=4-zx\\
z(x+y+z)&=8-xy
\end{align*}
what is the value of $|x+y+z|?$

(A) $2\quad$ (B) $2.5\quad$ (C) $3\quad$ (D) $3.5\quad$ (E) $4$

This is a problem from University of Waterloo's 2009 small C math contest. The correct answer is D, but there aren't any solutions on their website. I've found a system of equations that I solved for $3(x + y + z)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 28,$ but from there I'm not sure what to do. If anyone could show me how they did it, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Hint: the first equation $x(x+y+z) = 2-yz$ can be rewritten as $(x+y)(x+z)=2$.

Comment: yes this is a good hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from our System we get
$$(x+y)(x+z)=2$$
$$(x+y)(y+z)=4$$
and
$$(x+z)(y+z)=8$$
so we have by dividing
$$y=2x+z$$
$$z=x+2y$$
$$z=4x+3y$$ 
from here we obtain
$$y=-3x$$
$$z=-5x$$
plugging this in the first equation of our System
$$x(x-3x-5x)=2-15x^2$$
can you solve this?
for your control:
from here we get $$(x,y,z)=(\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};\frac{5}{2})$$ or
$$(x,y,z)=(-\frac{1}{2};-\frac{3}{2};-\frac{5}{2})$$